# Create a button inside a TableView in ios 6

Tags: button, ios6, tableview

Is it possible to create a button inside a TableView in ios 6?

An example would be in Settings --> Mail, Calender... --> Click on an existing email account (on iPhone). At the bottom of this view there is a "button' saying delete account.

Is this a button or just another cell made to look like a button?

I want to keep the standard background that comes with a TableView which is why I'm inquiring. I know I could make the TableView shorter and add a normal button.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my code on GitHub. https://github.com/eddieios/ECFormView

ECFormView uses a UITableView with a button added to the tableFooterView. I put the pertinent code below.

```
UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[footerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;
[self.tableView sendSubviewToBack:footerView];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[footerView addSubview:button];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 44)];
[button setTitle:@"Submit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//[button addTarget:self action:@selector(nextView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a button as a subview to the `tableHeaderView` or `tableFooterView` of a table view. This SO post describes some of the implementation: [Adding a UIButton in the header of UITableView header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866182/adding-a-uibutton-in-the-header-of-uitableview-header)

iOS 6 added a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` class that implements a *reusable* view for headers and footers. This can improve performance when dealing with large table views. See: [How to use UITableViewHeaderFooterView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900446/how-to-use-uitableviewheaderfooterview)